# statsmodels data update frequency

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

consider a vector with hourly observations, the data is updated every 12 hours.

with R, I could do

> ts(vector_with_R, frequency=12)

In statsmodels "freq" controls the units for the time series not the "data window". How can I change the "data window".

Comment: It's still not clear (without R knowledge) what do you exactly want. Can you provide expected output for statsmodels?

Comment: "ts(frequency=3200)" ===  the data is replaced every 3200x ,or new data after 3200 units. For hours the default is 1.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you need [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) - most popular python package for working with timeseries and another analytic data. Statsmodels work with it:

```
import pandas as pd
t=pd.TimeSeries(range(10), index=pd.date_range(start='2010-10-10 06:00:00', periods=10, freq='H'))
```

Comment: does not "periods" in pandas just give n observations,  rng = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H') ?

Comment: Yes, periods is observations number